# projectionStream is not a function in D3.js v4

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js

We are working on this website http://bandaultralarga.italia.it/mappa-bul/

On that page we have a gMap where we draw some polygons on top, using d3(v3) and topoJson.

Now we want (would like) to switch to the new v4 to add new data viz design on the page but keeping what we already had.

Troubles come in the overlay function below where we translate the coordinates into the Google Map system.

Referring to D3 v4 API Docs we switched from:

```
path = d3.geo.path().projection(googleMapProjection);
```

to:

```
path = d3.geoPath().projection(googleMapProjection);
```

but this generates the subject error (projectionStream is not a function.)

Any clue to get this to work again?

```
var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

overlay.onAdd = function () {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'svg_map';
    div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
    div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(div);

    overlay.draw = function () {

        var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

        var googleMapProjection = function (coordinates) {
            var googleCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);
            var pixelCoordinates = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(googleCoordinates);
            return [pixelCoordinates.x + 4000, pixelCoordinates.y + 4000];
        };

        path = d3.geoPath().projection(googleMapProjection); // Here is where troubles come

        generaOverlay(overlay, datiShape);

    };

};
overlay.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mbostock answer:

Please read the [d3-geo release notes](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/releases/v1.0.0) or [CHANGES.md](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#geographies-d3-geo):

“Fallback projections”—when you pass a function rather than a projection to [path.projection](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#path_projection)—are no longer supported. For geographic projections, use [d3.geoProjection](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#geoProjection) or [d3.geoProjectionMutator](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#geoProjectionMutator) to define a custom projection. For arbitrary geometry transformations, implement the [stream interface](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#streams); see also [d3.geoTransform](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#geoTransform).